# Intellij how to delete all line containing annotation?

Tags: intellij-idea

I want to delete all lines that contains annotation. I see there is a shortcut to delete line/selection. But how do i pass regex to the delete line shortcut so that all line that starts with `@` gets deleted?
I want to use like this
`^@`

Comment: Replace ```^.*@TheAnnotation.*$\n``` with empty

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have to use `replace` option.
Use `Ctrl+R` to open replace option, select regex(at the left side of search box there is a * sign). Enter `@.*$` in `replace box`. Keep the `replace with box` empty.

The Regex means any line starting with @ followed by zero or more characters(digit/non digit/letter etc) and ended by `end line`.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Following @mahfuj-asif answer, you can update your regex like this `\ \* @.*$|\/\*\*|\ \*\/`, to remove all generated annotations, by using the same principle.

For example if you have a code like this:

```php
    /**
     * @return int|null
     */
    public function getId(): ?int
    {
        return $this->id;
    }
```

And want to remove this part:

```php
    /**
     * @return int|null
     */
```